# How to place two Seeksbars at one place?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-seekbar, rangeseekbar

Here what I am doing is , I want to show the seekbar running in between  the RangeSeekBar (between the selected range). For that, I want to place these two seekbars at one position.

I don't know how to do that. I have tried RelativeLayout and FrameLayout but nothing happened.

Thank you.

**activity_play.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/pSeekBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="37dp" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:drawable/screen_background_light"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dip">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/selectedfile"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="middle"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Not file selected"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.util.rangeseekbar.RangeSeekBar
            android:id="@+id/rangeSeekBar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:max="100"

            android:paddingBottom="10dip"
            />


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:drawable/screen_background_light"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/MinEditText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/prev"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_previous" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/play"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_play" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/next"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_next" />


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/MaxEdiText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: do you have an image that will show us what do you want to do? Your description is not really clear!!!

Comment: I exactly want three thumbs on a seekbar. In which the right most and the leftmost thumb will be used as Range and the middle thumb would be able to move in between those ranges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can use this library its hard to write it yourself

https://github.com/syedowaisali/crystal-range-seekbar

Comment: I am already using this. It provides two thumbs only. I want to place two seekbars (SeekBar and RangeSeekBar) at on place (one over the another).

Comment: u should edit this library to achive your goal .u can not put another seekbar  on it .

Comment: How? Can you please tell me.

Comment: download the library source from github  and look how they write the range bar and try to add another thumb to that range bar  and use your new costum library as a module in your project

Comment: Yes and Thanks. I did it by using FrameLayout and android:layout_marginTop="30dp" and it worked